# Capturar evento de un kendo-grid en Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, kendoui

Estoy tratando de capturar un evento, cual sea, en un kendo-grid en Angular 8.2.2. Hasta ahora todo lo probado ha sido en vano, no emite evento alguno. El componente está montado tal que así:

```
<!-- Esta linea -->
<kendo-grid [kendoGridBinding]="gridDataSimpleVariable" [pageSize]="pageSize" [pageable]="true" [sortable]="true"
    [resizable]="true" (selectionChange)="onSelectionChange($event.selectedRows)">
<!-- Esta linea -->

    <kendo-grid-checkbox-column [width]="45" [headerClass]="{ 'text-center': true }" [class]="{ 'text-center': true }"
        [resizable]="false" [columnMenu]="false" [showSelectAll]="false">
    </kendo-grid-checkbox-column>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let cabecera of cabeceras">
        <kendo-grid-column *ngIf="cabecera.type === 'Id'" field="{{cabecera.field}}"
            title="{{cabecera.title | translate }}" [hidden]=true>
        </kendo-grid-column>
        <kendo-grid-column *ngIf="cabecera.type === 'Text'" field="{{cabecera.field}}"
            title="{{cabecera.title | translate }}" [autoSize]=true>
        </kendo-grid-column>
        <kendo-grid-column *ngIf="cabecera.type === 'Number'" field="{{cabecera.field}}"
            title="{{cabecera.title | translate }}" format="{0:0.00}" [autoSize]=true>
        </kendo-grid-column>
        <kendo-grid-column *ngIf="cabecera.type === 'Date'" field="{{cabecera.field}}"
            title="{{cabecera.title | translate }}" [autoSize]=true>
            <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
                {{ $any(dataItem)[cabecera.field] | localDate:DateFormat.MEDIUM:true }}
            </ng-template>
        </kendo-grid-column>
    </ng-container>
</kendo-grid>
```

Aporto todo el kendo ya que igual no se debe emitir el evento en dicha línea, aunque también he probado todos los eventos onChange, onSelectionChanged, etc y no ha dado frutos.

En el .ts se ha creado la función correspondiente:

```
public onSelectionChange(event: any[]): void {
    console.log('Cambio!');
  }
```

Pero no consigo, ni por activa ni por pasiva hacer que esto funcione. ¿Qué debería hacer?